# Error when creating project cordova-lib cordova-app-hello-world missing

Tags: node.js, windows, cordova, npm

I would like to start a new cordova project on Windows 10

I run the command

```
cordova create MyApp com.myapp myapp
```

I am getting the following message

```
Creating a new cordova project.
Could not find directory : C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-app-hello-world
```

My stack : node 4.2.1 npm 3.3.8 cordova 5.3.3

How can I fix it?

Comment: The issue is with cordova and node versions. Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/a/33544397/3543808

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cordova-lib node_modules repository is empty !

Run command

```
npm install
```

to the repository

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\
```

Comment: that means cd into the cordova-lib folder and run the command

Answer (score 7):

The same goes for [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) just :

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib
npm install
```

I'm just wondering why this is not done when installing cordova.