# Cordova: could not find directory

Tags: cordova, installation

I need to use Cordova to develop a mobile application for a project this semester and am having difficulties getting it up and running.  I followed [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/) tutorial provided by Apache.  When I run `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld` to create the Hello World application I get the following output:

> Creating a new cordova project.
>   Could not find directory: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/cordova-app-hello-world

I am trying to figure out what is going on, because everything up until the command seems to have been successful.  Right now I have the following installed:

- Node.js 5.0.0
- git 2.6.2
- Cordova 5.3.3
- Ant 1.9.6 (I was told this is needed to work with an IDE, so I installed it)
- Android SDK Tools
- Xcode

Comment: there are a few problems with node 5 and cordova, try with node 4

Comment: Using Node 4 fixed my issue.  Should this be translated to an answer?

Comment: I'll answer with my previous comment and update it once the cordova fixes are released

Comment: Cordova 5.4.0 is out, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there are a few problems with node 5 and cordova, they have been fixed but not released yet. For now, use node 4

Edit:
Cordova 5.4.0 is out and should work fine with node 5
http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/11/06/tools-release.html

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to go to the **/node_modules/cordova-lib** folder in the command prompt and run **npm install** command.

Comment: As you said, this is a *workaround*. So post it as a comment, not an answer!

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Cordova, did you use the -g paramter?

npm install -g cordova

Comment: this should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Known issues with latest (cordova 5.3.3). 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9712

Its fixed in the dev branch. Wait for the next release.